# how to get data from form post method in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have make one enquiry page in wordpress, when i will post that form then it will shows 404 error, can anyone help me please.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's hard to understad what' you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ elimantas : i have make one simple page in wordpress which contains the enquiry form, and my action is set to the same page, but when i submit the form then it will shows 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Set the `action` attribution to point to the correct URI.

Comment: it is going to the same url because i have not mention any action,

Answer (score 0):

is going to sound very strange but if you put the names of the field with some kind strange words like "abc" or "xyz" at the start of any field, is going to work, something like

```
<input type="text" name="xyzName" id="xyzName" />
```

should do the trick , make sure to do this with EVERY field, even the submit input, why it works? because wordpress has some hidden fields with the same name so you crash with them, so the solution? used names that you know that is not going to cross with the one of the wordpress

pd: remember use the same name in post to get the data $_POST['xyzName']

other tip, you can use "exec-php" plugin to be able to run some "php" code inside the "pages" of wordpress